# Google Maps Api v3 marker. google is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've a website with the google maps api which is loaded asynchronous. But this throws a errer: google is not found.
My code is:

```
<script>

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.817116, 4.780616),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    panControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    rotateControl: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'),
  mapOptions);
};

var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.817116, 4.780616),
  map: map
});

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&' +
    'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

addLoadEvent(loadScript);

</script>
```

When I delete the marker the code works correctly. Why is'nt it working if I add the marker as specified in some examples?

The addLoad is a load event. That's not the problem... Can anybody help me to get this working?

Comment: What is the implementation of addLoadEvent?  May not be the problem, but can't reproduce it without that.  Perhaps you can provide a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem?  Or a link to a live example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 until it is loaded.  Your marker creation is running before the API is loaded.  You need to move it in to the initialize function, which won't execute until the API is available.

```
<script>

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.817116, 4.780616),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    panControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    rotateControl: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'),
  mapOptions);

  var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.817116, 4.780616),
    map: map
  });

};  // end of initialize


function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&' +
    'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

addLoadEvent(loadScript);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your map variable locally within `initialize` which means that none of the other functions can access it. Declare it globally outside of `initialize`:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
  // code
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps', mapOptions);
}
```