# Cordova Google Map appears in lower version 4.1.2 Android phone but not in latest version Lollipop why?

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps

App was working fine in low version Android phone (tested on jellybean).It shows up Google map on lower version (4.1.2) android phone.

My script for calling Google map API is

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx"> </script>
```

In config.xml

list of permission given

```
 <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml under manifest

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

index.js

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapmake"), myOptions);
```

HTML meta tags

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"> 
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```

so why it is not working on latest **Android Phone(5.1.1)** it shows **BLANK** div?

Comment: could you try with googlemap api v3 which is without api key and check whether it is working or not.

Comment: It is not working for this  Google map API  URL                                          <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script> tried this but still not working log error:Refused to load the script 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. It works on older version android phone but Not in Latest Android version

Comment: also i am getting "google is undefined" error in latest version.

Comment: one thing instead of https use http... if not works then ,
check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386782/google-maps-api-v3-marker-google-is-undefined?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Thanks Banik .I finally solved problem map finally works.

Answer (score 0):

So These following Changes made to work my map

**1**.**Change your MAP Script link to below path(MAP API v=3)**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.3&sensor=false'></script>
```

**OR** (IF You want to embed other library ***Example in my case***:('places'))

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.3&sensor=false&libraries=places'></script>
```

**Note**:(  **After** script link of 
*jquery.min.js* and *index.js* ***then***
*Put This Map script link* )

**2**.**You might get below error sometime**

[Refused to load the script 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/…; because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.]

For this **Change meta http-equiv**="**Content-Security-Policy**"

from

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

Rest all are same .thank you.